# MySQL: Sorting results before group by statement

Tags: mysql

Basically, I have a coppermine gallery and I want to show the last 4 updated albums on the homepage. Here's the query that I've got so far. It basically gets the latest pictures. The subquery works fine on it's own but when it comes time to grouping them to get each album on its own, it doesn't seem to be getting the most recent one from the list.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
 SELECT c.cid, c.name AS catname, a.aid, a.title AS albumtitle, a.category, p.aid AS albumid,p.filepath,p.filename,p.ctime AS creationtime,p.title AS pictitle,p.approved
 FROM cpg145_pictures AS p LEFT JOIN `cpg145_albums` AS a ON p.aid = a.aid LEFT JOIN `cpg145_categories` AS c ON a.category = c.cid
 WHERE p.approved='YES' AND a.category IN (47,48)
 ORDER BY p.ctime DESC) AS T
GROUP BY albumid
ORDER BY creationtime DESC
LIMIT 4
```

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and desired result. That would be best for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. Apparently, in MariaDB you have to give the subquery a limit for it to be sorted correctly. So:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
 SELECT c.cid, c.name AS catname, a.aid, a.title AS albumtitle, a.category, p.aid AS albumid,p.filepath,p.filename,p.ctime AS creationtime,p.title AS pictitle,p.approved
 FROM cpg145_pictures AS p LEFT JOIN `cpg145_albums` AS a ON p.aid = a.aid LEFT JOIN `cpg145_categories` AS c ON a.category = c.cid
 WHERE p.approved='YES' AND a.category IN (47,48)
 ORDER BY p.ctime DESC
 LIMIT 200) AS T
GROUP BY albumid
ORDER BY creationtime DESC
LIMIT 4
```